# Why did their son had to die? 2 Samuel 11:1-27

Tags: deuteronomy, david

David Commits Adultery with Bathsheba, and  Bathsheba becomes pregnant. (2 Samuel 11:1-27)

**Why did their son had to die since Deuteronomy (24:16 NRSV) says :**

> 16" Parents shall not be put to death for their children, nor shall
>   children be put to death for their parents; only for their own crimes
>   may persons be put to death."

**And also why did God intervene?**

Comment: Even Solomon himself, who was not technically born of adultery, ended up committing some very serious sins, thereby inevitably leading to the breakup of the Kingdom into two parts (1 Kings 11:11), so one can only wonder what would have happened if one born of actual adultery would have inherited the throne...

Comment: @Lucian: Amnon was David's first son and heir to the throne-his mother was Ahinoam 2 Samuel 3:2 ,Amnon developed passionate feelings for his half sister Tamar which he violated , Absalom the brother of Tamar nursed hatred for Amnon and murder him. 2 Samuel 13 20-29

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the child's death is clearly given in II Samuel 12:14 :

> ... because by this deed thou hast given great occasion to the enemies of the Lord to blaspheme, the child also that is born unto thee shall die. [KJV]

The Lord had promised to David, by the mouth of Nathan the prophet :

> ... I will set up thy seed after thee, which shall proceed out of the bowels, and I will establish his kingdom. [II Samuel 7:12. KJV.]

This, of course, is prophetic not only of David's immediate seed (later to be seen in Solomon) but also prophetic of the everlasting kingdom to be set up through the reign of the son of David, Jesus Christ.

But neither the figure of the everlasting kingdom (Solomon) nor the fulfillment of that figure (the one born of the virgin Mary) would be permitted to come from the child born out of David's transgression.

The fruit of that transgression was not to be the one to fulfill either the figure or the reality of the everlasting kingdom.

The Lord gave and the Lord hath taken away; blessed be the name of the Lord, Job 1:21.

Comment: @ Nigel J :Amnon was David's first son and heir to the throne-his mother was Ahinoam 2 Samuel 3:2 ,Amnon developed passionate feelings for his half sister Tamar which he violated , Absalom the brother of Tamar nursed hatred for Amnon and murder him. 2 Samuel 13 20-29 .. David had six sons in Hebron before Solomon (1 Chronicles 3:1-10) .Daniel was his second son by Abigail, You have mentioned the  correct verse (2 Samuel 12:14 ). If the transgression was handled by human Judges, David and Bathsheba would have been stoned to death, including her unborn baby. So Why did God intervene?.